# Comobox and TextBox not displaying properly in ListView WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

The goal is to add a combobox and textbox to a listview so the user can select from or enter into each control. It doesn't show the control instead it displays a property of the control (for ComboBox it's the   items.Count and for TextBox it's .Text) instead of the actual control. I have looked at other examples online and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CompoundListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CompoundListView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="Lstv_UserControls" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                    
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Index" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ItemIndex}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=cmb_Type}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=txt_Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CompoundListView
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            ComboBox Cmb = new ComboBox();
            Cmb.Items.Add("Button");
            Cmb.Items.Add("TextBox");
            Cmb.Items.Add("Label");
            Cmb.Items.Add("CheckBox");
            Cmb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Text = "Name";
            txt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            Lstv_UserControls.Items.Clear();// Clear the list view 

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ListViewUserControl ListItem = new ListViewUserControl
                {
                    ItemIndex = i.ToString(),
                    cmb_Type = Cmb,
                    txt_Name = txt,
                };
                Lstv_UserControls.Items.Add(ListItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class ListViewUserControl
{
    public TextBox txt_Name { get; set; }
    public ComboBox cmb_Type { get; set; }
    public string ItemIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're binding to the combo box object itself, not its selected value.

Comment: Same with the text box.  You're binding to the text box object itself, not its text value.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear on what I was expecting. If I bind it to a property then it will display the value but I'm expecting it to display the ComboBox control and TextBox control so the user can select from the ComboBox and enter a value into the TextBox.

Comment: In my opinion, this will be much easier to do if you use a DataGrid instead of a GridView.

Comment: "*I'm expecting it to display the ComboBox control and TextBox control*" - as you see, that is a wrong expectation. And the approach of showing UI elements that were created in code behind is wrong in the first place. The UI elements should be declared by appropriate DataTemplates in the GridViewColumns.

Comment: Thanks for the comments they helped me reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I think I figured it out. There were a couple things wrong:

- Add a `<DataTemplate>` to each of the listview items. One for the
  ComboBox and one for the TextBox
- Corrected Binding for ComboBox `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cmb_Type.Items}"`
- Corrected Binding for TextBox `Text="{Binding Path=txt_Name.Text}"`

[image]

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="Lstv_UserControls" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Index" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemIndex}" />

            <GridViewColumn x:Name="gridC_Type" Header="Type" Width="200">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=gridC_Type,Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cmb_Type.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=cmb_Type.SelectedItem}"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn x:Name="gridC_Name" Header="Name" Width="200">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=txt_Name.Text}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=gridC_Name,Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Helpful resource:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5246161/Wpf-binding-combobox-in-a-listview